# layout React child, Objects are not valid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, promise

I'm getting one error in my layout dile:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I have DashboardLayout file, this is my code: (file dashboardLayout.tsx)

```
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Container from "./Container";
import RedirectLogin from "./redirectlogin";
import { 
    getSession, //service localhost:3000/session
    getPermissions //service localhost:3000/getPermissioms
} from "src/controllers/session.controller";
import { useRef } from "react";

type DashboardLayoutProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export default async function DashboardLayout({ children }: DashboardLayoutProps) {

    let cookie: string | undefined= "";
    let havePermissions = useRef(false);
    let dontHavePermisioms = useRef(false);

    cookie = document?.cookie
                            .split("; ")
                            .find((row) => row.startsWith("SESSION="))
                            ?.split("ID=")[1];
        
    if(cookie===undefined ){ 
    }else{
        await getSession({"id":cookie}).then( async (res) => { 
            const dataPermissions = {
                "id": res.data.id,
            }

            await getPermissions(dataPermissions).then((res)=>{
                const permiso = res.data.find((permision:any) => permision.permissionName === "moduleOne");
                if(permiso.effect===true){ 
                    dontHavePermisioms.current=true; 
                    havePermissions.current = true; 
                }else{ 
                    dontHavePermisioms.current=false;
                    havePermissions.current = false; 
                }
            });
        }) 
    }
    
    return (
        <Container>
            {   (havePermissions.current && dontHavePermisioms.current)?
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="flex flex-1">
                        <Sidebar />
                        <div className="p-5 w-[80vw] flex-grow">{children}</div>
                        </div>
                    <Footer />
                </>
                :
                    <RedirectLogin dontHavePermisioms={dontHavePermisioms.current} />
            }
        </Container>
    );
}
```

so, I have two conditions, one if cookie exists, ans two  is the user logged in, have permision to used it system, so I tried to get the permission using 2 services, one to get session data and two to get permission data, so I added to `await`  because this takes a while.

so, in my app.tsx I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: A react component can't be an async function. It has to return something renderable synchronously. Your function returns a Promise which is an object that react can't render. If you want to perform an async task use `useEffect` and update your component when the promise is resolved.

Comment: get it.... my main problem is on my ```getSession(```) and ```getPermissions()``` services, these services take a while to get their response,.... so do you think that I added the services inside a useeffect, the problem may be fixed???

Comment: Yes, if you add all the async operations in useEffect and load the ui based on the reponses of the getSession and getPermission (activity indicator)

Comment: ok, let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your component (which is a function) is asynchronous, and it contains a promise , so when you call this component (function) it returns a Promise (which is an object) instead of the JSX you wrote, so until this promise is resolved, it is still an object which is invalid as a child.

in react when you want to fetch data or make any asynchrounous job you should use the `useEffect` hook, then when the fetch is complete and the data is loaded update the state made by `useState` hook
this is the approach that you should be using

your code should look something like this:

```js
    export default function DashboardLayout({ children }: DashboardLayoutProps) {
    let [cookie, setCookie]= useState(document?.cookie
                            .split("; ")
                            .find((row) => row.startsWith("SESSION="))
                            ?.split("ID=")[1]) ;
    let [havePermissions , setHavePermission] = useState(false);
    let [dontHavePermisioms, setDonthave] = useState(false);

    useEffect( async () => {
   // here put your code and logic and use setState instead of directly assigning value
} , [cookie])

}
```